# Javascript : matching object properties pattern or prefix

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const obj = {
  obj_abc: '',
  obj_def: '',
  hello_123: '',
  hello_456: ''
}
```

If I have an object that its property has a certain pattern of prefix how can I split them into multiple arrays?

like

```
const arr1 = [{
  obj_abc: '',
  obj_def: ''
}]

const arr2 = [{
  hello_123: '',
  hello_456: ''
}]
```

I couldn't think of a way that I can partially match the properties of an object.

Comment: Why an array of one item as opposed to just the object itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` method on `Object.entries` and return one object with separate properties for each similar keys. This assumes you want to match part of the key before `_`

```js
const obj = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: true,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: true
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  const [key] = k.split('_');
  if (!r[key]) r[key] = {}
  r[key][k] = v
  return r;
}, {})

const [r1, r2] = Object.values(result)

console.log(r1)
console.log(r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My version using `Object.keys`

```js
const obj = {
  obj_abc: 1,
  obj_def: 2,
  hello_123: 3,
  hello_456: 4,
}
const arr1 = [];
const arr2 = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (key.match(/hello_.*/)) {
    arr1.push({
      [key]: obj[key]
    });
  } else {
    arr2.push({
      [key]: obj[key]
    });
  }
});
console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest answer using plain javascript**

```
const a = {
  obj_abc:123,
  obj_def:456,
  hello_123: 123,
  hello_456:456
};

const b = {};

for(k in a){
    const [key] = k.split('_');
    if(!b[key]) {
      b[key] = [];
    }
    b[key].push(a[k]);
}

console.log(b);
```